# socket.emit on sever side is ignored after connection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to make my code function so that on a io connection, i have a `socket.emit` right afterwards which saves a variable from my `server.js` to a `client.js`.

Strangely, when I was working on a school desktop computer, the code was working perfectly fine, but once I transferred the files to my home desktop, the code did no function properly

When the code is run from my application, the `console.log` on `client.js` does not occur

Relevant code:

server.js

```
var http = require('http').Server(app); 
var path = require('path');  
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var userLog = io.of('/logged');
userLog.on('connect', function(socket) {
// Send current user to client
socket.emit('saveUser', ({user:currentUser}))
console.log(currentUser + ' has connected');
}
```

client.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var me;
   socket.on('saveUser', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data[0])
    me = data.user;
    console.log("i am " + me);
   })
}
```

home.ejs

```
<script src="./socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>var socket = io('/logged');</script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/client.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `socket.on('saveUser', ...)` outside the `$(document).ready()` and put it right after you establish the socket.io connection.

If the `'saveUser'` message arrives before the document is ready, you will not have an event handler installed when the message arrives and you will miss it.

Comment: hey! thanks for the suggestion, moving socket.on('saveUser',..) outside the $(document).ready() function did the job. Also, do you know why the error did not occur on a different computer?

Comment: @Jacky - It's a race condition (timing sensitive).  If the socket.io connection finishes before the document finishes loading, then the problem occurs.  So, either a variation in doument loading time or socket.io connection time can cause the problem to occur or not occur.