# socket.io code organizing and timing ES6

Tags: javascript, websocket, ecmascript-6, socket.io

i have an experimental app that is pretty simple, you click a display button and an image appears in real time to all clients, utilizing socket.io. now it does work for the most part. however i had an issue (my original question here: [socket.io emit on connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617056/socket-io-emit-on-connect)) with an event not happening when the client connected, but i have resolved it with the help of this thread: [socket.emit on sever side is ignored after connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49747656/socket-emit-on-sever-side-is-ignored-after-connection).

basically, my 'new-client-append event' retrieves data (html in the form of a string) so that when a new client connects, it shows the same data that current clients see (similar to connecting to a chat room and being able to see all chat history). i had to reorganize my code so my 'new-client-append' event would take place, and i can get it to work if i put data in manually. my new issue is now that i have had to reorganize my code, my 'new-client-append' event is dependent on a variable i set within the class, so it is no longer recognizable. i'm relatively new to JS, how can i get my variable to be recognized and why is this happening? i had tried moving the event in different places of my code with no luck. it is the `this.mainContainer` variable.

CLIENT

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import SaveInput from './SaveInput';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

// make connection
const socket = io.connect('localhost:3000');


**socket.on('new-client-append', (data) => {
  console.log('NEW CLIENT ENTERED');
  console.log('on new-client-clone ' + JSON.stringify(data));

    this.mainContainer.append(data);

});**

socket.on('connect_error', function(){
    console.log('fail');
});


class Display extends SaveInput {

    constructor(){

    this.mainContainer = $('.main-container');
    this.pGrid = $('.pic-grid-container');
    this.display = $('#btn-display');

    this.buttons();
  }

  buttons (){

    // click buttons
    this.display.click(this.displayEls.bind(this));



  //display images 
  displayEls() {

    let img = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/22f38e0216f57af53a1776fb2a72c436?s=60&d=wavatar&r=g';
    let $picContainer = $('<div class="picture-frame"></div>');
    let  $newImg = $('<img>');

    // clone pic-grid-container
    let htmlClone = this.pGrid.clone();
    let stringClone = htmlClone.html();

    // EMIT

    //send image url
    socket.emit('client-image', {
      image: img
    });

    // send dom clone to server
    socket.emit('new-client-append', {
      clone: stringClone
    });

    // LISTEN

    // append image in real time
    socket.on('client-image', (data) => {

        let foo = data.image.toString();

        $newImg.attr('src', foo);
        // console.log(data);
        // console.log(foo);
        $newImg.appendTo($picContainer);
        this.pGrid.append($picContainer);

        // console.log('html clone ' + JSON.stringify(htmlClone));
        // console.log('string clone ' + stringClone);
    });

}

export default Display;
```

SERVER

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');


// app set up
const app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
// const  = new socket(server);
let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// static files
app.use(express.static('app'));

// socket setup & pass SERVER
const io = new socketIO(server);

let jqueryImage;

// on client connect
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log('client has entered...');

  socket.emit('new-client-append', jqueryImage);


    // events
    socket.on('client-image', function(data){
        console.log('SERVER ' + data.image);
        io.sockets.emit('client-image', data);
    });


    socket.on('new-client-append', function(data){
            jqueryImage = data.clone;
            console.log('jqueryImage ' + JSON.stringify(jqueryImage));
      });



    // errors
    io.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    io.on('connect_error', function(){
        console.log('fail');
    });

});


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server running....');
});
```

UPDATE

added suggested code, calling the maincontainer from the display object. but it is saying that it is not defined.

```
socket.on('new-client-append', (data) => {
  console.log('NEW CLIENT ENTERED');
  console.log('on new-client-clone ' + JSON.stringify(data));

    **display.mainContainer.append(data);**

});
```

file where i create the objects

```
import SaveInput from './modules/SaveInput';
import Display from './modules/Display';


const saveInput = new SaveInput();
const display = new Display ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your socket.on function has

```
this.mainContainer.append(data);
```

This implies that you've attached a mainContainer property to the socket object. Because you've not done this, but rather declared it inside your Display (sub)class, it's attached to the Display object you created.. I can't seem to find it, but somewhere, wherever this script is required there is a

```
variable = new Display();
```

You must call this mainContainer object by it's name. Find that code that initiates the Display object and then use

```
theVarNameYouFound.mainContainer.append(thatThing);
```

Comment: this makes sense. i adjusted my code to your suggest (edited it up above). now it is saying the display object is not defined.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work that way, unfortunately. This class is being exported, but the main script isn't being imported. Therefore, this variable does not exist within the scope of this js script.

Comment: Also, you are exporting and importing the Display class only, so the rest of the script is essentially useless.

Your socket code should be in with the script that creates the actual objects from that class. I probably should have specified that.